# Query returns no results when field is matched against string

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

That following resource http://dbpedia.org/page/Ulugh_Beg has a "foaf:name" field which has two values:

- Beg, Ulugh
- Ulugh Beg

Why then does this query return no results on http://dbpedia.org/sparql?

```
select ?article
where 
{
  ?article foaf:name "Ulugh Beg"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you see on http://dbpedia.org/page/Ulugh_Beg is an HTML rendering, and it doesn't always perfectly reflect the underlying RDF data.  If you scroll to the bottom of that page, there are some *Raw Data* links where you can browse the data in actual RDF formats.  For instance, if you grab the [N3/Turtle](http://dbpedia.org/data/Ulugh_Beg.n3) version, you'll see

```
dbpedia:Ulugh_Beg
  dc:description "Timurid ruler"@en , "Timurid ruler" ;
  foaf:givenName "Ulugh"@en ;
  foaf:name "Beg, Ulugh"@en , "Ulugh Beg"@en .
```

The name has the language tag *en*. If you want to query by name like this, you'll need to include that.  For instance:

```sql
select ?person where {
  ?person foaf:name "Ulugh Beg"@en
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fperson%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20foaf%3Aname%20%22Ulugh%20Beg%22%40en%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Yay.  I couldn't get _any_ sample query I tried to work, before that.

Comment: @WillBriggs yes, that was from an earlier version of the answer.  There's no mention of `some-language` anymore.  I'm confused, though;  are you the same as Chris, the asker?

Comment: @WillBriggs Ah, OK.  Just the way it was phrased, it sounded like you'd been waiting for an answer to this 2-hour old question.  Glad to hear it helped though;  there's lots of data available in DBpedia, and it can be a very useful source, especially with a very flexible query language like SPARQL.